# How to add Good Morning Salutation like Spotify in flutter application

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make salutation based on the timings in my app in flutter just like spotify -

[image]

Also i am having doubt regarding where to place this piece of code and if i paste it anywhere in main.dart. I get an error. The code-

```
  var timeNow = DateTime.now().hour;
  
  if (timeNow <= 12) {
    return 'Good Morning';
  } else if ((timeNow > 12) && (timeNow <= 16)) {
  return 'Good Afternoon';
  } else if ((timeNow > 16) && (timeNow < 20)) {
  return 'Good Evening';
  } else {
  return 'Good Night';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Widget that displays the text of your greeting. The Widget must also be in your build method to be displayed. Below is an example of a Text Widget displaying the greeting at the center of the screen:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('My Flutter app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(_getGreeting()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String _getGreeting() {
    var timeNow = DateTime.now().hour;

    if (timeNow <= 12) {
      return 'Good Morning';
    } else if ((timeNow > 12) && (timeNow <= 16)) {
      return 'Good Afternoon';
    } else if ((timeNow > 16) && (timeNow < 20)) {
      return 'Good Evening';
    } else {
      return 'Good Night';
    }
  }
}
```